# Vue v-radio on a previous invisible element

Tags: radio-button, vue.js

```
<div class="btn-group clearfix" data-toggle="buttons" v-radio="auth">
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" name="auth" value="1">
        Apple
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="auth" value="2">
        Banana
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default" v-if="isRich">
        <input type="radio" name="auth" value="3">
        Pear
    </label>
</div>
```

Here the third element has a `v-if` on the label, and originally `isRich` is false when page is loaded. Then, `isRich` is set to be true before click on the third element. But `auth` value is still 1 instead of 3.

How can I get 3 instead of 1 as `auth` value in this case?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Use v-model within your input elements on auth, see: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use v-model for this. 
See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio

```
<div class="btn-group clearfix" data-toggle="buttons" v-radio="auth">
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default active">
        <input type="radio" name="auth" value="1" v-model="auth">
        Apple
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="auth" value="2" v-model="auth">
        Banana
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default" v-if="isRich">
        <input type="radio" name="auth" value="3" v-model="auth">
        Pear
    </label>
</div>
```